# Connecting to URL requires authentication in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, https

I'm beginner in kotlin.
I'm try to connect to my http service, which requires authentication.

Have error:

> Unresolved reference: Authenticator

How can I set Authenticator?

```
var url = URL ("https://myURL")
val authenticator = object : Authenticator() {
    val passwordAuthentication: PasswordAuthentication?
        get() = PasswordAuthentication(
            "user",
            "password".toCharArray()
        )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that you've imported `Authenticator` at the top of you Kotlin file. I presume this is [java.net.Authenticator](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/java/net/Authenticator) that you are trying to use, in which case ensure your Kotlin file looks like this:

```kotlin
import java.net.Authenticator

val authenticator = object : Authenticator() {
    val passwordAuthentication: PasswordAuthentication
        get() = PasswordAuthentication(
            "user",
            "password".toCharArray()
        )
}
```